# Why can I not mix Guid and string members in a ComVisible struct?

Tags: c#, com, marshalling

Consider the following interface ([registered with `regasm /tlb`](https://github.com/mgaffigan/ComStringGuidMarshallingDemo/blob/master/ComStringGuidMarshallingDemo.Common/Register.bat) with a c# out of process [server](https://github.com/mgaffigan/ComStringGuidMarshallingDemo/blob/master/Server/Server.cs) and [client](https://github.com/mgaffigan/ComStringGuidMarshallingDemo/blob/master/Client/Client.cs)):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IComTestTarget
{
    InterestingRecord[] GetInterestingRecords();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public struct InterestingRecord
{
    public Guid guid;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string ChatText;
}
```

If I try to call `GetInterestingRecords`, I receive an exception in the server process:

> The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
>   at [GetRecordInfoFromTypeInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221422(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   at [OleVariant::CreateSafeArrayDescriptorForArrayRef](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/46ab1d132c9ad471d79afa20c188c2f9c85e5f20/src/vm/olevariant.cpp#L4363)
>   at System.StubHelpers.MngdSafeArrayMarshaler.ConvertSpaceToNative

If I comment out the line `public Guid guid;` or if I comment the line `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] public string ChatText;`, the call completes as expected.  If I change the interface to return a single value rather than an array, the call completes as expected.  What am I doing wrong?

Runnable minable example at [GitHub](https://github.com/mgaffigan/ComStringGuidMarshallingDemo)

Comment: This is strange. Guid is not an automation-compatible type, so it's seen as a VT_RECORD type. It should be handled by the CLR (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Record\{9C5923E9-DE52-33EA-88DE-7EBC8633B9CC}), and it *is* to some extent, but it looks like it's a problem inside another VT_RECORD... If you define your own guid: `[ComVisible(true)] public struct MyGuid { [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)] public byte[] data;}` and use it inside your record, it seems to work fine. double strange. looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @SimonMourier, that makes me feel better.  I love magnumdb.com by the way, very useful!

Comment: oh thanks for that :-) I'll be delivering an update with the new FCU Windows SDK soon.

Comment: Note: The same behavior occurs in a C++/ATL server with a `GUID` in a record type.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "same behavior" since .NET (Framework) implements lots of things above COM, but yes, GUID is not an COM/OLE automation type, whatever the language you use.

Comment: Sorry, @SimonMourier - that was more a “note to self”. It seems I’m still working in the same milieu since I rediscovered this issue yesterday when implementing a native server. Just confirms that it is a limitation of COM (not .Net)